# Math.random Scenario

Tags: java, math

**Example 1:** `50 + (int)(Math.random() * 50)` returns an integer between *50 and 99*. The maximum number in decimal form being 99.9 recurring.

**Example 2:** 
`34 + (int)(Math.random() * 21)` returns an integer between *34 and 55*.
The maximum number in decimal form being 54.9 recurring.

Why is it that example 2 returns 55 and not 54?

Comment: "The maximum number in decimal form being 54.9 recurring" Isn't really correct either. The maximum value of the expression `Math.random() * 21` is 21 times the largest `double` that is strictly less than `1.0`, rounded to the nearest `double`. I'm fairly certain that that value is strictly less than `21`, and quite certain that that value is not `20.999...`. Java floating point is binary, not decimal, so discussion of repeating nines is off base, quite literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns a decimal in the range of `[0.0, 1.0)`,

So your assumptions are correct in each example

For the first example, 50 + 49.9 = 99.9

For the second example, 34 + 20.9 = 54.9

I am not sure where you are getting 55 for example two because when the decimal is cast to an int, the decimal will lose its precision, effectively rounding it down to create the max of 99 for example 1 and 54 for example 2

**Edit**

The book is wrong, if you wanted the range to be 34 to 55, the code would have to be

```
34 + (int)(Math.random() * 22)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is from a textbook or tutorial? The second example is wrong. It should say "34 to 54", just like you thought it should.

Comment: This is from a book called "Introduction to Java Programming" by Y. Daniel Liang. Both physical and online versions have example 2 written as the answer. I've also found a few universities using this as an answer to the problem too.